# Run a Program inside a loop in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have exe of [cwebp](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/cwebp) that basically can be run like

```
cwebp.exe image1.jpg -o image1.webp
```

I'm trying to create simple powershell script to run the exe for all image inside a folder using powershell script, I do have create some script like this

```
param ( [string]$FolderName)
Get-ChildItem $FolderName | ForEach-Object {
    &"D:\Downloads\libwebp\bin\cwebp.exe" $_.FullName -o $_.BaseName + ".webp"
}
```

so I can run the ps1 file with the folder name like

```
batch-script.ps1 ".\images"
```

but when I run it, got error

```
SHCreateStreamOnFile((const LPTSTR)filename, STGM_READ, stream) failed 80070002
Error opening input file .webp (80070002)
OpenInputStream(filename, &stream) failed 80070002
cannot open input file '.webp'
Error! Could not process file .webp
Error! Cannot read input picture file '.webp'
```

the folder content just have jpg image name image1.jpg, image2.jpg, did I miss something?

Comment: You should simply output the created command line you create inside your loop to check what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
param ( [string]$FolderName)

$images = Get-ChildItem $FolderName

foreach ($img in $images) {
  $outputName = $img.DirectoryName + "\" + $img.BaseName + ".webp"
  &"D:\Downloads\libwebp\bin\cwebp.exe" $img.FullName -o $outputName
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is correct when I test it, looks like I need to create the output file first and my code also missing the DirectoryName that make the converted image is placed in the same folder as the ps1 file.